# Is there are any general solution that can handle adding same generic type addition in chisel3?

Tags: scala, oop, chisel

I was trying to make generic hardware class module, which is written in chisel3.

My codes look like below.

```
class hardware_module[T <: Data](bandwidth: T)extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in0 = Input(bandwidth)
    val in1 = Input(bandwidth)
    val out = Output(bandwidth)          
    })
    io.out := io.in0 + io.in1
}
```

Error message looks like this

```
type mismatch; found: T requried: String
```

Through internet, i found that this error message comes from adding two generic type at the same time. I want to know that there are general solution about this problem in Chisel3 too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is defined only for some `Data` sub-classes (e.g. `Bits`) and not defined for `Data` in general. Either bound to [Num[T <: Data]](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.4.3/chisel3/Num.html) or use Structural Types pattern (a.k.a Duck Typing) https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-duck-typing-in-scala-structural-types/